# Sumar en MySQL solo si cumple cierta condición

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente tabla y necesito realizar una suma, a continuación el problema.

TABLA:

[image: Tabla]

Como pueden ver el producto ya viene totalizado o sumado lo que fue recibido, sin embargo se repite la cantidad total recibida las veces que venga en un contenedor lo cual finalmente me duplica el resultado agrupado.

El resultado que necesito obtener es:

[image: Resultado]

El que hoy obtengo es y que es INCORRECTO es:

[image: Inconrrecto]

Comment: Bienvenido Bastian a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la suma de la tabla previamente agrupada según los campos que quieras. Supondré que el campo "Producto" es el principal y agrupare sobre ese y su cantidad recibida.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(t1.cant_recibida)
FROM (  SELECT
            a.cant_recibida
        FROM tabla_principal
        GROUP BY   -- Aqui esta el truco
            a.Producto,
            a.cant_recibida) t1
```

Y, al menos con los datos que ingresaste, resulta

```
SUM(t1.cant_recibida)
---------------------
                 3850
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer la suma y eliminar los valores duplicados lo puedes hacer de esta manera

```
SELECT SUM(COLUMNA_SUMA) AS SUMA FROM(SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMNA_DUPLICADA),COLUMNA_SUMA FROM TABLA
```

Espero que sea de ayuda